# Have a visible HTML element but out of the positioning workflow

Tags: css

My biggest problem here is to express what I want, so please free to alter the formulation / suggestion correct wording for things.

On mobile I wish my page to be only vertically scrollable (page width and view port width are the same. A bug is causing an element adding more width than it should. I have identified the culprit element, when I set this element style to "display:none;" the display is correct (no horizontal scroll), when I don't I get an horizontal scroll.

To make it clear, with ".culpritElement {display: none}":

[image: without the culprit element]

With culpritElement visible:

[image: with the culprit element]

culpritElement is generated with some inline style by a third party library that I don't want to tweak. Is there a CSS directive to set to make the element visible but out of the positioning flow of the others (and page size computing).

Comment: `position: absolute` or `: fixed`, basically. That takes it out of the document flow entirely, and then it's just a matter of setting its position so it is visible.

Comment: @MarcB Both don't change a thing (the problem is still appearing).

Answer (score 0):

You could set `.culpritElement { max-width: 100vw; overflow-x: hidden; }`

Or you could apply the above css style to its parent element

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden` applied on the body happened to hide the whole element.

Comment: @AsTeR Is there more on the HTML structure or a simple example on JSFiddle? if `overflow-x: hidden` hides the whole element, all I can imagine is there is no actual vision of `.culpritElement` inside the viewpoint

Comment: The thing is that I don't want hit to be hidden, I just want the rest of the view layout to not be altered. The container has only absolute children, so everything is overflowing.